# Delete where in clause in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following queries in sqlite which I am using in Xamarin Forms.

`allProdsId` is initialized as:

```
allProdsId = new List<Products>();
```

First of all, I made a query which retrieves all products ID from the table products. Then I want to delete all orders where orders have `ProdId` all the `allProdsId` retrieved.

The delete query is not working. Can someone please help me to achieve the `WHERE IN` clause in sqlite using xamarin forms ?

```
allProdsId = _con.Query<Products>("Select ProdId from Products");

con.Execute("DELETE FROM Orders WHERE ProdId = ?", allProdsId);
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: if you want to match against multiple values in SQL, use the IN keyword, not '='

Comment: Does sqlite support the `IN` keyword ?

Comment: @Jason : Is it supported or there is an another alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a comma separated string of all the ProdIds that you wish to delete and insert that directly into the SQL string.

```
var productIDs = conn.Query<Products>("Select ProdId from Products");
var prodIDCommaString = string.Join(",", productIDs.Select(p => p.ProdId));
var deleteCount = conn.Execute("delete from Products where ProdId in (" + prodIDCommaString + ");");
```

Comment: Thanks. 

Can we do it using foreign key, like using cascade delete ? Please advise.

Comment: @cholo That is a totally different question and it depends upon how you have defined the  `FOREIGN KEY`  and the `REFERENCES` and if you have enabled `ON DELETE CASCADE` within your tables.

Comment: My question is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775275/cascade-delete-in-sqlite-xamarin-forms 
which was left unanswered.

Comment: What do you mean by `only the key(s) of the top-level record` ?

Is the foreign key not considered ?

Comment: If you are deleting a record that has `on delete casade` and you are not preventing the children from being deleted automatically via foreign key references, then all the referenced records are deleted (assuming nothing else is referencing them, review http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help @SushiHangover

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I have tried your solution with regard to the answer. I noticed that the code gets executed but it actually does not delete the data in the db. However, when I hardcode the values within the query, the values get deleted. Can you figure out what's wrong ? I've been struggling about this the whole day. Please help.

Comment: Kindly advise on how to resolve the issue if possible :)

Comment: @cholo Confirm that the SQL statement string you are creating is valid (that is includes the correct product id and that they are comma separated)...

Comment: Yes. I confirm the SQL statement is valid. I executed it on DB browser and its working correctly. var prodIDCommaString is returning me a string. 

The SQL statement that works both on DB browser and in the code (when hardcoded) is like this : `delete from Products where ProdId in ('1', '2', '3')`

Can you confirm `"delete from Products where ProdId in (" + prodIDCommaString + ");"` generates the correct query ?

Comment: @cholo Can I confirm? It is your code, I use that with SQLite all the time, move that SQL string creation out of the Execute statement and debug it.

Comment: Yep I removed the SQL string creation and it works fine with hard coded values. I still cannot figure out what's wrong with the SQL string creation though.

Comment: @cholo keep the SQL statement creation, just move it outside the Execute statement and debug the string...

Comment: Yep. Thank you :)